# How is $\sum_{q}{e^{-i\ {q} \cdot(x-y)}}=\delta(x-y)$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, fourier-transform, dirac-delta-distributions

Evening all,

I'm working through some practise problems at the very beginning of a QFT text book, the question I'm having trouble with is as follows:

Given $[\hat a_{\bar p} ,\hat a_{\bar q}^\dagger]=\delta_{\bar q\bar p}$, show $$\frac{1}{V}\sum_{\bar q\bar p}{e^{-i(\bar q \cdot \bar x-\bar p\cdot \bar y)}}[\hat a_{\bar p} ,\hat a_{\bar q}^\dagger]=\delta(\bar x-\bar y)$$

My algebra takes me to:
$$\frac{1}{V}\sum_{\bar q}{e^{-i\bar q \cdot (\bar x-\bar y)}}=\delta(\bar x-\bar y)$$

I can see the LHS is $1$ when when $\bar x=\bar y$  but I can't get anywhere with $\bar x\neq \bar y$.

I'd appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: The LHS is $V^{-1}\sum_{\overline{q}} 1 \rightarrow \infty$ when $x = y$. This might be a better question for math.stackexchange.com since it's primarily related to [completeness relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_functional_calculus#Resolution_of_the_identity).

Comment: The phases will all cancel out. It's the same idea as in the Fourier transform.

Comment: Can you add angle-wise evenly spaced unit vectors vectors around a circle?

Answer (score 0):

Since $\delta(x)$ is a distribution, not a function, if you want to show some expression to be equal to it, you want to integrate both sides. You're trying to show that
$$
\frac 1 V \sum_{\vec q} \exp\left(i \vec q \cdot \vec x\right) = \delta(\vec x)\text,
$$
which is true iff
$$
\int f(\vec x) \sum_{\vec q} \exp\left(i \vec q \cdot \vec x\right)\;\mathrm{d}x = V f(0)\text.
$$
Since the summation can be moved outside the integral, the LHS is just the sum of a bunch of Fourier coefficients.
$$
\sum_{\vec q} \int f(\vec x) \exp(i \vec q \cdot \vec x) \;\mathrm{d}x
$$
At this point, the next step depends on what set of $\vec q$ you're summing over -- I'll leave that for you to think about. However, you should see at this point that the result should be proportional to $f(0)$.